# Dynamodb component for Delphi

Tags: delphi, amazon-dynamodb

I'm looking for a [Dynamodb](http://aws.amazon.com/pt/dynamodb/) Delphi component. Does anybody know someone ?

In Delphi XE2 we have support to SimpleDB, are there too much difference btw SimpleDB and DynamoDB protocol ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any delphi component, however, if you feel like doing it yourself, you can read the api reference here http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/operationlist.html

Answer (score 0):

The OP found his answer at the following links

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/operationlist.html
   http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html

Answer (score 0):

There is now an ODBC driver and a set of FireDAC components for DynamoDB from CDATA

https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/dynamodb-odbc-delphi.rst